# JSON.NET: How to deserialize from specific json object to a class with a different name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

This is driving me kinda nuts, because we don't have time to ask for the API team to change their response object name.

We have a json results that reads:

```
"seqRing": {
      "admStatus": "disabled",
      "status": null,
      "lines": null
    },
```

And I need that the json deserialization map it to this class:

```
public class SequentialRing
    {
        public string admStatus { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<SeqLinesAttr> SeqLines { get; set; } = new List<SeqLinesAttr>();
    }
```

If this were a case of a difference in the property name, I could simply use the JsonPropertyAttribute at the top of the property, but I need something similar for the class.

If there's something I could use? Please.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like "seqRing" is a property in a larger JSON object. Is that correct?

Comment: @devNull erm... yes it is. So what you are thinking is to use the JsonPropertyAttribute inside the class where SequentialRing is a property? Will that work?

Answer (score 3):

The JSON that you've shown has "seqRing" as a property of a larger JSON object. In order to deserialize that, you can create a wrapper class (or using an existing class) where you can specify the JSON property name for the class:

```
public class SequentialRingWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("seqRing")]
    public SequentialRing SequentialRing { get; set; }
}
```